# How to formalize the following statement: "for all integers, n, n^2 is even."

Tags: calculus

I am trying to formalize the statement "for all integers $n$, $n^2$ is even" by using mathematical quantifiers but I am not sure if I am on the right track.
I'd be grateful if someone could shed light on it.

Comment: $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists k\in \mathbb{N} | n^2=2k$ (note that this statement is false: $3^2=9$).

Comment: I would recommend that you always include what you already have worked out yourself, or you face the danger that your question becomes closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{N}$ stands for natural numbers.

Since you want to state for all integers, you need to modify  $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists k\in \mathbb{N} | n^2=2k$$ to

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}, \exists k\in \mathbb{Z} | n^2=2k$$